Which comedy film contains a highly stylized, rapidly cut sequence of drinking?
I'm looking for the name of a comedy film that contained a highly stylized, rapidly cut sequence involving drinking. The scene is shot from above, looking straight down to the character, who tilts his head back and essentially throws the drink down his throat.
There was traveling involved, and possibly Brad Pitt or Johny Depp in there somewhere. It's the rapid cutting of images, drinking, and the swooshing sound effect, along with a suggestion of humor somewhere below the surface.
I was reminded of this film by a similar sequence I happened to see here at 02:36, but I am only interested in finding the title of the feature-length film.

@Pᴇᴛᴇ yep I'm looking for a feature film, but I'll try to check it out - looks fun!

I've edited my question to make it clearer that I'm interested only in finding this film. If the link to the scene that reminded me is a problem, It can be deleted as well. I've included it only because it does a good job of supplementing my description.

One movie this style of jump cutting is definitely used in is Snatch - Brad Pitt is the lead actor, which fits with your description. It's used in the scenes where cousin Avi comes over to London to claim the stolen diamond. The distinctive whoosh sound even features, if memory serves. 




Wow - that's it exactly! Going to have to watch it again now. The only thing I could think of was Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas - around the same time. Thanks!
